# Wagtail ModelAdmin with list_filter error: FieldDoesNotExist: Region has no field named 'p'

Tags: python, django, django-models, wagtail, django-modeladmin

I've got a model I'm exposing through Wagtail's `modeladmin` that works until I try to apply a `list_filter` including a ForeignKey. I've got a self-referencing model (to store Counties, Cities, and Towns) called Region that I'd like to be able to create a filter on by the `Parent` level.

I'm running Wagtail 1.8.1 on Django 1.10. Here's the model:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    """
    Tree of regions and sub-regions.
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'Region',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'parent')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(
            self.name,
        )
```

And the `ModelAdmin` from `wagtail_hooks.py`:

```
class RegionAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Region
    menu_icon = 'doc-full-inverse'
    empty_value_display = 'ROOT'
    list_display = ('parent', 'name')
    list_filter = ('parent')


modeladmin_register(RegionAdmin)
```

It works fine if I comment out the `list_filter` line in the class `RegionAdmin`. The documentation says it can take a `ForeignKey` in the list. Am I missing something obvious? Stack trace is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 43, in _cache_controlled
    response = viewfunc(request, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/decorators.py", line 24, in decorated_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/options.py", line 350, in index_view
    return view_class.as_view(**kwargs)(request)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 67, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 63, in bound_func
    return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/views.py", line 249, in dispatch
    self.queryset = self.get_queryset(request)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/views.py", line 554, in get_queryset
    filters_use_distinct) = self.get_filters(request)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/contrib/modeladmin/views.py", line 381, in get_filters
    field_path)[-1]
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/utils.py", line 485, in get_fields_from_path
    fields.append(parent._meta.get_field(piece))
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/sepia/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 619, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist('%s has no field named %r' % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Region has no field named 'p'
```

Thanks for any help or ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a comma:

```
list_filter = ('parent',)
```

Without the comma, the parentheses are ignored and django will be iterating the string, and not a tuple (because there is no tuple!), hence the attempt to access field `p`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but effective.

Comment: Excuse me while I go kick myself for about an hour! Thank you.

Comment: Excused, Sir! ;-) Be gentle!